# Simple encryption of all letters in ascii code using a hash table

Tags: c, hash

I want to do the following:

If you have any letter, I want to use its ascii code to make a simple encryption method.

For example, if I have letter 'H' its ascii code is 72. Then, the encryption would be (72 mod 60) +1 = 13. 13 would be the 'key' and the encrypted letter would be just 72 + key = 72 + 13 = 85.

I think I have something but I get collisions and I've tried several ways but I still can't deal with them. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct letter{
    char letter;
    int key;
    char criptedLetter;
}letter;

int hash (int n);

int main() {
    printf("\nEncript the alphabet with a hash table");
    int i=0;
    char n = 'A';

    letter * alphabet = calloc(60, sizeof(letter));
    letter x;
    while(i<=25){
        x.letter = n;
        int asciiOriginalLetter = n;
        int key;
        key = hash(x.letter);
        if(alphabet[key].key != 0){
            do{
                key++;
                if(key == 60){
                    key = 0;
                }
            }while(alphabet[key].key != 0);
            x.criptedLetter = (int)x.letter + key;
            alphabet[key] = x;
        }
        else{
            x.criptedLetter = (int)x.letter + key;
            alphabet[key] = x;
        }
        i++;
        n++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<60; i++){
        printf("\nIn position %d there's letter %c with key %d and cripted letter %c", i, alphabet[i].letter, alphabet[i].key, alphabet[i].criptedLetter);
    }
    return 0;
}

int hash (int n){
    int key;
    key = (n % 60)+1;
    return key;
}
```

Note: yesterday I did a similar question and some of you gave amazing help, this is the new code.

Comment: `hash (int n)` returns [1...60]. `alphabet[key]` is valid for `key` [0..59].  Review indexing.

Comment: Why do you have an array size 60 if you are just doing the letters of the alphabet? Also in your example for 'H', you said the encrypted letter is 85, are you wanting that to be ASCII 85 ('U')? If that is the case what do you want something like 'K' to do? 'K' = 75 key = 16 encrypted letter = 91 which is [. Do you want these types of characters?

Comment: [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1Sji) is a demo of it encrypting just the letters of the alphabet. Not too sure what your desired result is though.

Comment: Maybe you want Caesar cipher which is based on using modulus operator. See [example](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/11/caesar-cipher-c-c-encryption-decryption.html) Otherwise this doesn't have anything to do with hash. Note, there is cryptographic hash which is one way, it can't be decrypted. Then there is simple obfuscation, such as the ancient Caesar cipher. Then there is modern encryption such as AES.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'll check the links you included